# Need to get only number to numbers table to view in contacts list

Tags: php, html, css, laravel

> Contact Model

```
public function number()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Number');
}
```

> Number Model

```
public function contact()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Contact');
}
```

> Controller

```
    public function viewContacts(){
    $contacts = Contact::with('number')->get();
    return view('contacts.view_contacts')->with(compact('contacts'));
}
```

}

> my view

```
@foreach($contacts as $contact)
<tbody id="myTable">
  <tr>
    <td>{{ $contact->name}}</td>
    <td>{{ $contact->address}}</td>
    <td>
        @foreach ($contacts as $number)
          {{ $number->number }}
        @endforeach
    </td>
    <td>
        <a class="btn btn-xs btn-info" href="{{ ('edit-contact/'.$contact->id) }}">Modifica</a>
        <a href="{{ ('/delete-contact/'.$contact->id) }}" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span> Elimina</a></td>
    </td>
  </tr>
  @endforeach
```

> the results is:
> [image]

**But I need to see only the numbers associated with that contact**

> In Numbers table I have contact_id for reference.
> thanks so much. help me.
>
> tables:

[image]
[image]

Comment: If you want to see `numbers` for each `contact`, why are you doing `@foreach ($contacts as $number)` instead of `@foreach ($contact->numbers as $number)`???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
@foreach ($contact->number as $number)
   {{ $number->number }}
@endforeach
```

Comment: @TimLewis thank you I changed it to `contact` anyway the object would be `number`, `$contact->number`

Comment: Woops, you're right. The method name is `number`. It _should_ be `numbers`, since it returns more than 1, but that's a different issue :)

Comment: @TimLewis thanks for make me 1k, 1k thank you  <3

Comment: Haha, didn't even notice the score :) Congrats on the milestone!

Comment: @TimLewis and if I need to display only the numbers associated with that contact on another page, what can I do?

Comment: @EsTeAa and if I need to display only the numbers associated with that contact on another page, what can I do?

Comment: @AntonioPalermo If you have a new question, please open a new question; don't post it in the comments here. This is a QA site (question + answer), one question with 1 accepted answer (or multiple supporting answers). That being said, it should be the same approach. `foreach($contact->number)` can be used anywhere you've defined `$contact` as a single instance of your `Contact.php` model.